# Rails active record relationship category and subcategory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Basically, my teacher only created one model which is "categories" but then when we run the seed file:

```
Category.create([
{ name: "community", url: "community" }
]);

Category.create([
{ name: "activities", url: "activities", parent_id: 1 },
{ name: "artists", url: "artists", parent_id: 1 },
{ name: "childcare", url: "childcare", parent_id: 1 }
]);
```

As you can see there is a reference on the second Category.create.

And then on the Category model, I saw this:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Category", optional: true
    has_many :subcategories, class_name: "Category", foreign_key: :parent_id, dependent: :destroy
end
```

As you can see, my teacher did not create two different models to do the relation which looks confusing to me.

And then on the `public_controller.rb` file he puts:

```
def home
    @categories = Category.where(parent_id: nil)
end
```

Which also a bit confusing to me.

Can anyone explain the model association made above line by line in layman's term?

Sorry I was so confuse and a newbie here.

Comment: If there's a teacher involved, there's some work to do on your part, my friend ;)

a couple of hints: one to many, self join ...

enjoy your adventure ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a self join relationship, it's pure SQL, and Active Record has its way to make it work.

The line

```
belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Category", optional: true
```

is making a relationship between the categories table to itself, where the `class_name` is needed, because by convention Rails will use the first argument to infer the table name. The third argument `optional` states that there's no constraint for new records to be created with a `parent_id`. That strategy is what makes a category and a subcategory; categories don't have a `parent_id`, while subcategories must have one.

The foreign key is also inferred from the first argument `parent`, so the relationship is based on the column `parent_id`.

The second line

```
has_many :subcategories, class_name: "Category", foreign_key: :parent_id, dependent: :destroy
```

makes another relationship from categories to categories as well, but for you to have an easy way to access to subcategories having the category or vice-versa. The `class_name` remains the same, as it's the same table, but this time the `foreign_key` can not be inferred, so you must be explicit, the fourth argument `dependent: :destroy` is what makes every subcategory associated to a category to be destroyed when their category is destroyed, leaving no "*orphan*" records.

How do you get only categories and not subcategories?

```
Category.where(parent_id: nil)
```

By querying the categories table and filtering those rows with no `parent_id`.